# Insert Multiple Input Data with same name using Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I'm sorry I know this was asked many times, but I tried everything I see and still its not working. I have multiple input textbox in a column of *DataTable*. I'm using **ColumnDefs** for array of input boxes.

I want to send the array data with just one button click to the database using only one input field with same name.

I have a problem because I want to put it into the database which is I can't.

View:

```
// remarks
// total of 41 column input box inside the datatables.
{
      "render": function ( data, type, row){
           return '<input id="'+row[0]+'" name="my_remarks[]" type="text" value="'+data+'" class="form-control input-md" /> ';
       },// row[0] is the id 
       "targets": 9
},
```

And this is the button triggering to pass the array to database.

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>Admin/sendRemarks" class="btn green-jungle pull-right">Submit</a>
```

I don't know what to do to my Controller and Model. I have tried many codes but still it's not working.

Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATED:**

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC7q5.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: @GufranHasan updated my post with picture

Comment: "remarks" data @GufranHasan

Comment: see this https://www.patchesoft.com/datatables-with-codeigniter-server-side-sorting-part-3